# Enigmatic Python expression

Tags: python, initialization, generator

Could anyone explain the expression that initializes `mbr2`?

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self, param1, param2=None):
    self.mbr1 = param1
    self.mbr2 = ({}, param2)[bool(param2)]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I just figured out what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic selects one of two values from the tuple depending on the *truthiness* of the `param1`. If `False` the tuple is indexed with 0, otherwise 1; bools are easily coerced to integers.

It can be more clearly expressed using a ternary operator:

```
self.mbr2 = param2 if param2 else {}
```

Or short-circuiting with `or`:

```
self.mbr2 = param2 or {}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is a (weird) way to do the following:

```
self.mbr2 = param2 if param2 else {}
```

That it's more Pythonic.

Basically it will choose between the two elements on tuple (`({}, param2)`) if `param2` is *truthy*(1) or *falsy*(0) (`bool(param2)`)

Answer (score 0):

whenever `param1` is ['truthy'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/4954037), `self.mbr2 = param1`. otherwise `self.mbr2 = param1`.

note: `True == 1` and `False == 0` (and `bool` returns one of these).

the more pythonic way is:

```
self.mbr2 = param2 if param2 else {}
```